# Implement svg version of css background-size:cover not working perfectly

Tags: php, css, svg

I am using Imagemagick to generate images from pre-computed svg. The svg comes from   compiling some information captured from the editor we built. On the editor, we use css styling to preview live changes .

Now when we want to render actual image,we take the basic information to generate an actual svg which is then converted to flat image using imagemagick library.

Everything works perfect except the part where the css background styles is implemented using svg pattern.
Below is the css code

```
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: -134px -2px;
```

Below is the sample of the generated svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200" overflow="visible" fill="#000">
            <defs>
                <pattern id="bg_40b043e9944a4239b118e0b938054afb" x="-67%" y="-1%" width="100%" height="100%">
                <image preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" width="200" height="200" xlink:href="imagedata" />
                </pattern>
            </defs><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#bg_40b043e9944a4239b118e0b938054afb)" /></svg>
```

Details to consider

1. Parent svg is 200x200
2. Raw background position  is x:-134px and y:-2px but converted to percentage as -67% and -1% respectively.
3. Without the positioning, everything works perfect.

Considering the above, I think the problem is with the pattern image x,y offset (I guess) and the width/height also.
Below is the output of both svg and css version of the background

Rendered image from svg
[Rendered image from svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU1zv.png)

Snapshot of the html version with css.
[Snapshot of the html version with css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJp7J.png)
The image used for the background
[The image used for the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHz1i.jpg)

The second result is what we want to achieve throughout.

The complete svg used for generating the first image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200" overflow="visible" fill="#000">
        <defs><pattern id="bg_40b043e9944a4239b118e0b938054afb" x="-67%" y="-1%" width="100%" height="100%"><image preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" width="200" height="200" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHz1i.jpg"  /></pattern></defs><svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 200 200" x="0%" y="0%"><g opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" fill="url(#bg_40b043e9944a4239b118e0b938054afb)" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-dashoffset="0"><rect width="100%" height="100%"   /><svg class="layer" overflow="visible" preserveAspectRatio="none" id="layer_1535228794723_0887552009010049"  width="160.4065" height="38.7969" x="16.75" y="66"><g id="translateLayer" ><g id="effectLayer" fill="#000" stroke="#c01d1d" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 -26.09375 144.59375 29.6875" preserveAspectRatio="none" overflow="hidden"><g  font-size="25" font-family="ABeeZee" font-style="Normal" font-stretch="Normal" font-weight="400"><text y="-3"><tspan x="0">T</tspan><tspan x="14">e</tspan><tspan x="27">x</tspan><tspan x="40">t</tspan><tspan x="50"> </tspan><tspan x="57">o</tspan><tspan x="72">k</tspan><tspan x="85"> </tspan><tspan x="92">h</tspan><tspan x="107">e</tspan><tspan x="121">r</tspan><tspan x="131">e</tspan></text></g></svg></g></g></svg></g></svg></svg>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your Imagemagick version, date and platform. `convert -version`. What SVG renderer are you using with Imagemagick. It can use its own internal MSVG/XML or RSVG delegate or Inkscape in order of higher quality and accuracy. Check `convert -list format` and look at the line for SVG and see which renderer it is using. If it say XML, then I would recommend that you install RSVG or better Inkscape. Installing Inkscape on your system will mean you do not have to recompile Imagemagick as you would with RSVG, provided you are using a modern version of Imagemagick.

Comment: Your SVG file above does not render like either image you show, either by displaying in my Chrome browser on via Imagemagick convert with RSVG. Is that the same SVG file used to create your two images? Please post the actual SVG file used to generate your two other example results.

Comment: @fmw42 the image used for the pattern is base64 encoded and huge so I stripped them. Secondly I dont think it has to do with the imagemagick library. Just the right way to implement the css background-size:cover;background-position:x y with svg pattern. It will be rendered perfectly

Comment: @fmw42 I have updated to include the complete svg file

Comment: `@WebICT By Leo`. ImageMagick with RSVG abort traps on your SVG file for me using IM 6.9.10.11 Q16 Mac OSX and produces an image with only the red text. My GraphicConverter tool shows it fully, but with the wrong color in the pink background area. Using ImageMagick with its internal MSVG, produces an output with only the background and no text. Perhaps your SVG file does not conform to proper SVG syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only achieve what you want if you explicitely enter the size of your background image. CSS can tile the image along its inherent size because the image itself is its subject. In SVG, the pattern is the parent of the image, and the size of the tiles is set independently from that of the image.

A second complication comes from the fact that `width` and `height` in percentages are in relation to the width and height of the referencing `<rect>`. and 100% for both result in the tile having the same size as the rect. It also means that, whatever you set, the aspect ratio of the tile has a fixed relation to the aspect ratio of the *referencing* element, not the contained image.

You need to retain the aspect ratio set by the image for the pattern. The most stable way to do this is to use userspace coordinates, as percentages would always change when the aspect ratio of the `<rect>` changes.

Set `patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`, retain the original size of the image (image offsets need to be scaled accordingly), and then you need to set a `patternTransform=scale(...)` to fit the pattern tile size to your `<rect>` in the way `cover` would do.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="200" height="200" overflow="visible" fill="#000">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="bg_40b043e9944a4239b118e0b938054afb"
         patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-2010" y="-30" width="4500" height="3000"
         patternTransform="scale(0.0667)">
      <image width="4500" height="3000" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHz1i.jpg"  />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#bg_40b043e9944a4239b118e0b938054afb)" />
</svg>
```

(That is really the same as what your CSS reference would result in.)

Comment: Please how did you come about the scale value for patterntransForm ?? @ccprog

Comment: The height of the image is smaller than its width, so to cover the viewport the height defines the minium scale: height of viewport / height of image = 200 / 3000.